# In a Nuxt SSR application, what happens on server and what on client?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, nuxt.js

I'm on Nuxt 2.13 and building an e-commerce website.

But the are some issues with my server resources, my first load of site takes some time (on route change every thing is ok and fast, just the init is slow).

So i wanna know which parts of my site will be on server and which parts on client browser.

for example as recommended, i use `fetch()` with `axios` to get page/component data. as i read the docs it is said on render route it is server-side and on navigation it is client side. so what does that mean? my `axios` call in `fetch()` in on server or client? what about my other axios calls in `methods` to backend?

what i wanna understand is that which parts are on server? and can i make them client-side to save server resources? (I'm afraid with some users the resource usage get too high!!)

Answer (score 1):

That's point of fetch. It's called when it's needed. On server side during initial page load, than all page state is send along with rendered page to client. All following navigation is calling fetch on client side only.

On basic level, you can't care about it.
In reality, to speed up initial load, you may decide to load something always on client. Then you can move it to mounter() hook which is always called only on client side.

Comment: tanx. but there is still something i don't get. initial page load means when i hit the page for the first time or when i hit the whole site url for the first time (for example i go to `example.com` and the fetch is ssr, navigate to `/about` is server-side or client-side? navigate back to `index` is on server or client) ?

Comment: whole site. And you must navigate using router-link (instead of using plain a href which would cause page reload from server)